# Why a Bean is being used in this example - it appears like pointless indirection?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

In [this example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/enableasync-async-controller) of how to set up an Asynchronous service, for some reason the RestTemplate is set up in a very circuitous fashion.

Why can't the asynchronous routine itself just declare a new RestTemplate?

```
@Service
public class AsyncService {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncService.class);

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<EmployeeNames> getEmployeeName() throws InterruptedException
    {
        log.info("getEmployeeName starts");

        EmployeeNames employeeNameData = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/name", EmployeeNames.class);

        log.info("employeeNameData, {}", employeeNameData);
        Thread.sleep(1000L);    //Intentional delay
        log.info("employeeNameData completed");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(employeeNameData);
    }
 //...
```

Comment: If this is having the same service provide the `@Bean` that is then directly injected back in as `@Autowired`, it does seem a bit pointless. Maybe the idea is that it would allow to optionally inject the RestTemplate from somewhere else while still providing a default? Maybe it just an oversight.

Comment: Best leave a comment on that article. You can refer to your thread here in that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't the asynchronous routine itself just declare a new
>   RestTemplate?

Clearly no value here.
`RestTemplate` can be created simply with the `new` operator if not reused somewhere else.
Declaring it as `@Bean` makes sense if we want to reuse it somewhere else.
It indeed provides the singleton injectable/reusable in another bean that requires that.
But generally we don't do that in a `@Service` class like in this code but in a more global configuration class.

Comment: Is there any conceivable reason why a RestTemplate should be a singleton?    IE any reason not to just construct it inside the service worker routine?

Comment: 1) To avoid creation of similar objects. `RestTemplate` construction does some things 2) About your second question : defining a dependency in the class with a constructor allows to switch/mock this dependency. It also allows  to use a common instance (configured as you want to). If you "hide" the `RestTemplate` inside the method, you lose these advantages.